# How to send the longitude and latitude (GPS coordinates) to a Server

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, maps, latitude-longitude

I made a simple Android application which gives the latitude and longitude of the place where I am via GPS and I want to send the coordinates to a Webpage and represent them on google maps.
Which is the simpliest possibility to send the data to the server ?

Answer (score 4):

Post it to a webserver that is waiting for your data.

Answer (score 1):

Android uses [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/package-summary.html) for http communications. Use it to post the data to your server. Of course you also need to build a web application that will take latitude and longitude and navigate a google maps component to that position.

Edit: If I understood correctly from your comments, you want to open a specific url in your Android phone. You can do this with the following code:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(intent);
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for details.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer,i will try it with the HttpCLient and see if it works.

Comment: the Web application is already done,but how can i send this link:http://www.myserver.com/testf.php?c1=longitude&c2=latitude from my android application to the web application ?